# Why are copy-capturing lambdas not default DefaultConstructible in c++20

Tags: c++, c++20

C++20 introduces `DefaultConstructible` lambdas. However, [cppreference.com states](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) that this is only for stateless lambdas:

> If no captures are specified, the closure type has a defaulted default constructor. Otherwise, it has no default constructor (this includes the case when there is a capture-default, even if it does not actually capture anything).

Why does this not extend to lambdas that capture things that are `DefaultConstructible`? For instance, why can `[p{std::make_unique<int>(0)}](){ return p.get(); }` not be `DefaultConstructible`, where the captured `p` would be `nullptr`?

Edit: For those asking why we would want this, the behavior only seems natural because one is forced to write something like this when calling standard algorithms that require functors to be default-constructible:

```cpp
struct S{
  S() = default;
  int* operator()() const { return p.get(); }
  std::unique_ptr<int> p;
};
```

So, we can pass in `S{std::make_unique<int>(0)}`, which does the same thing.

It seems like it would be much better to be able to write `[p{std::make_unique<int>(0)}](){ return p.get(); }` versus creating a struct that does the same thing.

Comment: You had me until the last word, where I thought the captured `p` would be `make_unique<int>(0)`. Because allowing `p` to be `nullptr` would violate an invariant. The lambda's captures always set `p` to a non-empty `unique_ptr`. The body of the lambda may assume that `p` is never null, and allowing a default-constructed lambda to have a null `p` would be a bug that would be nearly impossible to track down: You scour every use of the lambda, and it always initializes `p`, and yet somehow, 10 minutes later, you find yourself with an instance of the lambda with a null `p`!

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify why a lambda that never returns a null value should be default-constructible, creating a lambda that _does_ return a null value?  That doesn't seem desirable or intuitive.

Comment: What would you do if the captured object does not have a default value/constrcutor?  What do you do for references?

Comment: What algorithm requires a default constructible functor?  AFAIK they only require them to by copy constructible.

Comment: I'm sure there are others. But, things like `std::upper_bound` require the `Iterator` type to be DefaultConstructible because it probably internally wants to make a temporary `It middle`. If I were to create `TransformIterator<T, F>` that applies a transform function, then using a lambda would not work. But, using a struct would.

Comment: For that you need to write a struct anyway because the `Iterator` type has requirements that a lambda will not satisfy.

Comment: A lambda is shorthand for writing a functor.  A `TransformIterator` while performing a transformation, also needs to be an iterator and that isn't something a lambda expression is made to create.

Comment: I meant the lambda would be the `F` type and the class `TransformIterator<It, F> {It it; F f;}` would satisfy everything else.

Comment: For something like that, you can get rid of `F` and use a `std::function` instead like `template <typename It> struct TransformIterator { using value_type = typename std::iteator_traits<It>::value_type; It it; std::function<value_type(value_type)> f; };`

Comment: I know this, but `std::function` as some overhead. Anyways, I don't really care about the use-case, I was just wondering why the standard does not just add ` = default` constructor to the lambda closure type.

Comment: Case in point doing `std::function<int*(void)>([p{std::make_unique<int>(0)}](){ return p.get(); } )` basically does the same thing by wrapping the lambda in something with `= default` constructor where invoking a default constructed object is discouraged, but still valid syntax.

Comment: [The first draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0624r1.pdf) of the paper proposing "default constructible lambdas" includes this restriction.  It could be presumed that this is because a captureless lambda can always be default-constructed, while a lambda with captures introduces many complications.  Would a captured `int` be `0` or uninitialized?  What would a default-constructed reference _reference_?

Comment: @DrewDormann Couldn't the closure type define a `= default` constructor and the compiler would handle this with the normal methods? ie: If you capture a reference, it would fail to compile. But, if the captured object is DefaultConstructible, it would work.

Comment: I imagine something like this https://godbolt.org/z/Tc75aY6f4 could be doable?

Comment: @Deev: Note that `std::transform_view` requires `regular_invocable`, which has the built-in requirement of either being completely stateless or that state changes do not affect the equality of the output. So if the "captured" value is default constructed, that could represent a different result. Thus breaking `regular_invocable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two reasons not to do it: conceptual and safety.

Despite the desires of some C++ programmers, lambdas are not meant to be a short syntax for a struct with an overloaded `operator()`. That is what C++ lambdas are made of, but that's not what lambdas *are*.

Conceptually, a C++ lambda is supposed to be a C++ approximation of a *lambda function*. The capture functionality is not meant to be a way to write members of a struct; it's supposed to mimic the proper lexical scoping capabilities of lambdas. That's why they exist.

Creating such a lambda (initially, not by copy/move of an existing one) outside of the lexical scope that it was defined within is conceptually vacuous. It doesn't make sense to write a thing bound to a lexical scope, then create it outside of the scope it was built for.

That's also why you cannot access those members outside of the lambda. Because, even though they could be public members, they exist to implement proper lexical scoping. They're implementation details.

To construct a "lambda" that "captures variables" without actually capturing anything only makes sense from a meta-programming perspective. That is, it only makes sense when focusing on what lambdas happen to be made of, rather than what they are. A lambda is implemented as a C++ struct with captures as members, and the capture expressions don't even technically have to name local variables, so those members could theoretically be value initialized.

If you are unconvinced by the conceptual argument, let's talk safety. What you want to do is declare that any lambda shall be default constructible if all of its captures are non-reference captures and are of default constructible types. This invites *disaster*. Why?

Because the writer of many such lambdas *didn't ask for that*. If a lambda captures a `unique_ptr<T>` by moving from a variable that points to an object, it is 100% valid (under the current rules) for the code inside that lambda to assume that the captured value points to an object. Default construction, while syntactically valid, is semantically nonsense in this case.

With a proper named type, a user can easily control if it is default constructible or not. And therefore, if it doesn't make sense to default construct a particular type, they can forbid it. With lambdas, there is no such syntax; you have to impose an answer on everyone. And the *safest* answer for capturing lambdas, the one that is guaranteed to never break code, is "no."

By contrast, default construction of captureless lambdas can never be incorrect. Such functions are "pure" (with respect to the contents of the functor, since the functor has no contents). This also matches with the above conceptual argument: a captureless lambda has no proper lexical scope and therefore spawning it anywhere, even outside of its original scope, is fine.

If you want the behavior of a named struct... just make a named struct. You don't even need to `default` the default constructor; you'll get one by default (if you declare no other constructors).